# How to read two or more attributes from the node in XPath?

Tags: php, html, xpath

foe example :
html:

```
<div  id="1" class="op" style='display: none;'>
<h4>a</h4>
<h4 >b</h4>
</div>
```

---

Query:

```
$elements = $xpath->query("//div[@id='1']@style='display:none;']/@id/@style");


echo @id
echo @style
```

but does not work!

Comment: you're missing the closing `[` and `'display: none;'` !== `'display:none;'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo missing `[` on your query and use `normalize-space`:

```
$elements = $xpath->query("//div[@id='1'][normalize-space(@style = 'display: none;')]");
if($elements->length > 0) {
    echo $elements->item(0)->getAttribute('class');
    // foreach($elements as $e) {

    // }
}
```